# How to execute Python file on Google Colab and save state on notebook's RAM?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I wish to write Python files from the code written on my notebook's cells, that I can execute, and save the state on the notebook's runtime memory.

Below is what I tried to do.

[image]

An explanation of why the above didn't work doesn't suffice to mark this question as solved.

The requirements for the solution are:

1. Being able to execute a Python file on the notebook,
2. **AND** save the state on the notebook's runtime memory.

My use case requires being able to accomplish both conditions, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you can do this by importing the file instead of executing it.

```py
%%writefile file.py

a = 1
b = 2
print(a + b)
```

and then

```py
import file
```

you can than access the variables via

```py
file.a
file.b
```